# MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: with mongoose save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this model with username and email set uniqe to false

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 20,
    unique: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 64,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  mailboxLink: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: nanoid(),
  },
  createdat: { type: String, default: dateJakarta },
});
```

and 1 user in my mongodb database

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"622eec9de7f66d1d633061e7"},"username":"jhon","email":"email@gmail.com","mailboxLink":"mfdYTDK","createdat":"2022-03-14 14:19:01","__v":0}
```

but when i'm trying to register the same username and email

```
userRouter.post("/register", async (request, response) => {
  const newUser = new userSchema(request.body); // body: {username, email}
  await newUser.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const token = newUser.generateAuthToken();
      response.status(201).json({
        token,
        user,
        message: "Register successfully",
      });
    }
  });
});
```

i got this error from `console.log(err);`

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: PigeonProjekt.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "email@gmail.com" }


  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { email: 1 },
  keyValue: { email: 'email@gmail.com' }
```

could someone help me solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that you have a mongo index `email` that is unique in your users collection. If you delete that index, everything should work. Try in your mongo shell: `db.your_collection_name.dropIndex("email_1")` or through your mongodb graphical tool

Comment: you were right i have email with uniqe in my collection, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try dropping the database or the collection itself then test again. If you first set the email field to `unique: true` and then inserted the user that you have in the database, but later changed the `unique` value of email to `false` in your schema, this will not update the collection itself. In short, rules in the database for email `unique: true` still apply and you need to remove them.